# how to enable UnitHelper in codeception for unit tests

Tags: codeception

I am trying to setup unit testing using codeception.  I have followed the [guide](http://codeception.com/docs/06-UnitTests) and have the following:

`unit.suite.yml`:

```
class_name: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled: [UnitHelper, Asserts]
```

When I try to run `codecept build`, I get the following exception:

```
[Codeception\Exception\Configuration]
UnitHelper could not be found and loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

UnitHelper is not a built-in class, but a helper class generated for unit suite.

You have to execute this command to create it:
`codecept generate:suite unit Unit`